# Mysql distance to line

Tags: php, mysql, geospatial

I try to create a system for detecting if a sporter is on the route that he has to do. Therefor I have a component where I can draw the route they should do. That route is stored in mysql, using LINE.

The next step I do is when I have a coordinate of the user, is finding if the distance between the user and the line. I use for that this query:

```
select *, st_distance(point(50,2),map_points) from tbl_route_new
```

This returns good information (I think), but this is how I see the information:

```
3.7770580579682638
```

Can someone tell me how I can know what the real distance is. I think this is in degrees. If I try some converters I find across the Internet I get a value, but that value is wrong unfortunatly.

If this isn't possible, then I will use PHP to do the calculations, but I think mysql is faster, then a loop over all the points.

Comment: Do you want to find out distance between to points and you have lat-log of those points in your table, right ?

Comment: I have the data as LINE in my database, because it needs to be the distance from the POINT (I give) to a line (in the database).

Comment: Could it be the same units as `50, 2`?

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to convert that to km. Or is there any reference-guide?